# the reset function and associative arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to loop through an associative array with the help of the functions `current()`, `next()` and `reset()`. The first two functions work great for me but when I want to loop through it again and use the `reset()` function it won't work.

Here's the code:

```
while ($availability_per_date = mysql_fetch_assoc($availability)) {

    //it won't go in to the loop below a second time
    while (current($room_types_available)) {

        $key= key($room_types_available);

        if ($availability_per_date["{$key}"] == 0) {                
            $room_types_available["{$key}"] = 0;
        }
        echo $key;

        next($room_types_available);
    }
    reset($room_types_available);
}
```

Comment: I hope this is purely academic and you're not using `current()`, `next()` and `reset()` because you think you **have** to?

Comment: I agree with Nick. It is far more intuitive to use foreach here.

Comment: actually it is not academic is there a problem using those methods?

Comment: It is more intuitive to use foreach... PHP is more or less designed with that in mind. At a bare minimum, it removes two lines of code and makes it easier for future programmers to immediately understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, try to use built-in functions that can easily work better with your code, here's an example:

```
while ($availability_per_date = mysql_fetch_assoc($availability)) {
    //it won't go in to the loop below a second time
    foreach($room_types_available as $key=>$value){
        if ($availability_per_date["{$key}"] == 0) {                
            $room_types_available["{$key}"] = 0;
        }
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

If it gives any bugs with your app, post it and we'll fix :)

Comment: thanks missed the tutorial on foreach loops, apparently it was an importent one :) going to try that right now...

Comment: worked so good it made me a little bit ashamed of myself... thank's a lot! i was stuck on that for three days. talking about learning the hard way :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the return of current($room_types_available) the second time through returns a value that casts to false?

Using the [each()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) function is a good way to solve the problem, it avoids ambiguity on false.

Comment: well i cant think of any other possibility... though i thought that the reset should fix that...

Comment: Try to debug your program because there is nothing wrong with it.Personally I think $room_types_available is empty.

Comment: it's easy to check, before the loop to $test = current($room_types_available);

Answer (score 0):

Not to copy on someone else's answer, but preinheimer is correct.

In the first iteration of the loop, you are setting a number of values to false (the string of "0" is false in PHP). While is then detecting these in subsequent calls and then terminating prematurely (because current, in this case, is returning false). Your two options are using each (as suggested by preinheimer) or foreach instead of while (as suggested by Khez).

Personally, (as I stated in the comments above), I view foreach as *far* more intuitive and therefore better practice, but neither of the two are functionally incorrect.

Comment: I like foreach for simplicity, but it does duplicate the array to be iterated over.

Comment: the foreach solution was great thank you all... don't know what i would without this site!